# Getting a localStorage string into img src tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have two values I need to get into a HTML file. I'm storing them in localStorage, the h1 element is fine as it's just a string I need. However, the second one is an image. I have the path stored in localstorage, but how can I drop it into the src attribute?

I've attempted it as it is below with no success, any help would be great.

```
<h1>Question 2</h1>
<h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(localStorage.quest2);
  </script>
</h1>

<img src="" id="q2">

<script type="text/javascript">
  var newPic = localStorage.picture;
  document.getElementById('q2').src = newPic;

</script>
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, are you sure localStorage.picture returns a value and is set correctly? It might be worth adding an if condition to check. If it does exist, maybe try using [set attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) instead of just .src

Comment: Rookie error! pulled in the value rather than the key. First time writing Javascript in 2yrs!!